# compiling error while building android source

Tags: android, compiler-errors, makefile, android-source

Iam trying to build the android source code following the guide on the android dev website. When I get to the "make" part, I get the follow output. Can anyone help me to resolve this error?

Thx,
Frans

```
frans@frans-laptop:~/android-platform$ sudo make
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.3.0.2.0.1.0
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
cts/bionic/libc/Android.mk:570: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target        /product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_so.o'
bionic/libc/Android.mk:570: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_so.o'
cts/bionic/libc/Android.mk:576: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtend_so.o'
bionic/libc/Android.mk:576: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtend_so.o'
cts/bionic/libc/Android.mk:584: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_static.o'
bionic/libc/Android.mk:584: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_static.o'
cts/bionic/libc/Android.mk:590: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o'
bionic/libc/Android.mk:590: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o'
cts/bionic/libc/Android.mk:599: warning: overriding commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtend_android.o'
bionic/libc/Android.mk:599: warning: ignoring old commands for target `out/target/product/generic/obj/lib/crtend_android.o'
build/core/base_rules.mk:166: *** cts/bionic/libc: MODULE.TARGET.STATIC_LIBRARIES.libc_common already defined by bionic/libc.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running  **make clean** and then run **make**

Comment: I redownloaded the source code and now it works like a charm:-)